# Android Embedded Fragment

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

New job, new project.  I'm walking into code that has Fragments within fragments within fragments.  (The deepest example I've seen so far is 5 fragments deep, but I'm still new to the code.)

I've read about Android UI optimizing and how flattening a layout can improve performance.  Does this same principle apply to fragments?

thanks for the help,
eimmer

Comment: I'd recommend you to not make fragment modules but to make code modules with sw rendering to single (max. two) fragment layers. I cannot think of situation to create such deep fragment structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the fragments will be nestled in the same way.

You can use [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) to inspect your layouts. Great when optimizing the structure!

Cheers!